# Haskell: Lazily read binary file with binary

Tags: parsing, haskell, binary, conduit

I'm trying to read in a binary file and parse it lazily using the 'binary' package. The package documentation gives an example of how to do this without forcing all the input for a scenario very similar to mine:

```
 example2 :: BL.ByteString -> [Trade]
 example2 input
  | BL.null input = []
  | otherwise =
    let (trade, rest, _) = runGetState getTrade input 0
    in trade : example2 rest
```

However, this uses the deprecated `runGetState` function, which itself points you towards the `runGetIncremental` function.

The problem is that the 'runGetIncremental' function seems to force the remaining input to be a strict bytestring, thus forcing it to load the whole file into memory. Indeed, I'm seeing memory usage of around 6GB when I try to run this. Even the implementation of `runGetState` now seems to be based on `runGetIncremental` and then reconverts the strict bytestring back to a lazy one using `chunk`.

Can I get the behaviour as described in the tutorial, or is this now unsupported by binary? If the latter, what's the best way to do this? I have a little experience using conduit, but it's not clear to me how I could use it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`pipes-binary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-binary) and [`pipes-bytestring`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-bytestring).  Here's a helper function for your benefit:

```
import Control.Monad (void)
import Data.Binary
import Pipes
import Pipes.Binary (decodeMany)
import Pipes.ByteString (fromHandle)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import System.IO

decodeHandle :: (Binary a) => Handle -> Producer a IO ()
decodeHandle handle = void $ decodeMany (fromHandle handle) >-> P.map snd
```

The `void` and `map snd` are there because `decodeMany` actually returns more information (like byte offsets and parsing errors).  If you actually want that information, then just remove them.

Here's an example of how you might use `decodeHandle`, using a quick skeleton for `Trade` I threw together:

```
data Trade = Trade

instance Binary Trade where
    get   = return Trade
    put _ = return ()

instance Show Trade where show _ = "Trade"

main = withFile "inFile.txt" ReadMode $ \handle -> runEffect $
    for (decodeHandle handle) $ \trade -> do
        lift $ print (trade :: Trade)
        -- do more with the parsed trade
```

You can use `for` to loop over the decoded trades and handle them, or if you prefer you can use pipe composition:

```
main = withFile "inFile.txt" ReadMode $ \handle -> runEffect $
    decodeHandle handle >-> P.print
```

This will be lazy and only decode as many trades as you actually need.  So if you insert a `take` in between the decoder and the printer, it will only read as much input as necessary to process the requested number of trades:

```
main = withFile "inFile.txt" ReadMode $ \handle -> runEffect $
    for (decodeHandle handle >-> P.take 4) $ \trade -> do
        ... -- This will only process the first 4 trades

-- or using purely pipe composition:

main = withFile "inFile.txt" ReadMode $ \handle -> runEffect $
    decodeHandle handle >-> P.take 4 >-> P.print
```